# Java: anonymous enums?

Tags: java

Does Java have the possibility of anonymous enums?

For example, I want my class to have one variable, whose value can be one of 5 different settings. So obviously that variable should be an enum. But this is the ONLY place where that particular enum will be used. Normally I would declare an enum type right above the variable and then declare the variable to be that type, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way. Does Java support anonymous enums?

Example:

```
public class Test {
    public enum Option {
        FirstOption,
        SecondOption,
        ThirdOption
    }
    Option option;
}
```

Is there a way to avoid declaring `public enum Option` and instead simply allow the option variable to be set to either FirstOption, SecondOption or ThirdOption with no notion of the "Option" type?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No Java does not support anonymous `enum`s.

Just declare them inside the class with no external visibility:

```
public class Test {
  private static enum Option {
    FirstOption,
    SecondOption,
    ThirdOption
  }

  Option option;
}
```

Comment: How do you assign a value to `option` from an outside class if the enum type is private? What benefit does setting its type private have?

Comment: @Ricket in the example above, `Option` can only be accessed within the `Test` class, which is what you described wanting

Comment: How did you intend to assign it when it was anonymous? Setting the Enum to private allows you to hide it from users of your api. You can assign the value from outside by taking a `String` and using `Option.valueOf(String)`, or any input indication you'd like really. In general it doesn't make sense to anonymize or hide Enums like you are asking for.

Comment: @Rocket perhaps I misunderstood your question but it sounded like it was only going to be used inside the class, hence I made it `private`. If you want to use it outside the class then `public` is the obvious choice. But if you use it outside the class, you will need a name for the type because a parameter or variable or return type will need to be declared of that type.